# How do I dynamically change the content of a item layout inside a listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-viewholder

I'm trying to change  the content of a single item in a listview, once a certain button inside this item (the layout that is), is pressed. I've written below how I'm trying to do it in the adapter.

```
View mCurrentConvertView;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.the_list_view_item_layout, parent, false);
    }

    mCurrentConvertView = convertView;

    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description)).setText("A Text");

    ((Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onButtonClicked(mCurrentConvertView);
            }
        });

    return convertView;
}

private void onButtonClicked (View mCurrentConvertView) {
    ((TextView) mCurrentConvertView.findViewById(R.id.description)).setText("A Different Text");
}
```

I also tried to put "notifyDataSetChanged()" at the end of the onButtonClicked() method but to no avail. Through debugging, I know that the onButtonlicked() method is being called when I click the button.

EDIT: I managed to make it work using a ViewHolder, setting it as a tag of the button, and passing it as parameter to the onButtonClicked();

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    onButtonClicked((ViewHolder) v.getTag());
}

private void onButtonClicked (ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.description.setText("A Different Text");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a methode in your adapter to change the content of an item, and refresh the adapter using notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to make it work using a ViewHolder, setting it as a tag of the button, and passing it as parameter to the onButtonClicked(); I edited the original comment with an explanation.